# How to send signal SIGUSR1 to daemon from Apache PHP script (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: php, linux, apache, signals, daemon

I thought this would be really simple, but apparently not.

I have a daemon (currently being tested as as normal executable actually), and I need to control what it does from a web page. Sitting in the middle is a MySQL database containing all necessary data passed in both directions. All on the same machine.

When a command is issued from the web page, PHP puts appropriate data into database, daemon reads it and acts. So far, so good.

However, daemon polls database, so there is a time lag. What I want to do is send daemon a message to say 'look now'. So I thought I'd send it a signal - SIGUSR1.

This works absolutely fine when the signal is sent from the command line (kill -SIGUSR1 .... ), but not from PHP - system("kill -SIGUSR1 ....").

So I thought - internal shell command, so put the kill command in a shell script. Again, works fine when run from command line, but not from Apache PHP system() API.

Tried the same thing using PHP posix_kill(), that failed as well.

Appears to be a permissions issue. Apache script user does not have permission to issue kill command. So I thought, OK - just for testing anyway - SUID the script. You can't SUID scripts, or so it appears.

So, sudo'd the script in the system() call, adding the script and user (www-data) to /etc/sudoers.d so there would be no sudo password prompt. The kill or pkill command in the script still comes back with code 1 (permission denied) - but it's running as root.

So I'm stuck. It seems a simple thing - send the daemon a signal to say 'wake up'. But, I cannot find a way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, very strange, after a reboot and no other changes the sudo approach suddenly worked. Summary:

1. Create script containing the (pkill) command
2. Place in /usr/local/bin and make executable
3. Add www-data to sudoers for this command (new file in /etc/sudoers.d)
4. Call from PHP Apache script as system("sudo /usr/local/bin/script_ name")

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very clever, but entirely unnecessary when using

```
PHP Version => 7.0.33-0+deb9u12
```

My current system has no trouble with

```
exec( "/var/www/MsgToLogger \"$msg\"", $r );
```

However this fails on my development system using

```
PHP Version => 7.4.33
```

saying "sh: 1: /var/www/MsgToLogger: not found"

It does look like a bug.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33476364)